# k8s docker container mounts the host, but fails to output log files

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

The k8s docker container mounts the host, but fails to output log files to the host. Can you tell me the reason?

kubernets yaml like this

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: db
  namespace: test
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: db
        image: postgres:11.0-alpine
        command: 
          - "docker-entrypoint.sh"
          - "postgres"
          - "-c"
          - "logging_collector=on"
          - "-c"
          - "log_directory=/var/lib/postgresql/log"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
          protocol: TCP
        volumeMounts:
          - name: log-fs
            mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/log
      volumes:
        - name: log-fs
          hostPath:
            path: /var/log
```

Comment: Are you sure you're looking on the right host?  It has to be on the node running the pod, not your local machine.  If multiple pods with this configuration get scheduled on the same node they'll conflict, and if the node gets deleted you'll lose these logs.  It might work better to send logs to the container's stdout, and use one of the setups described in [Logging Architecture](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/) in the Kubernetes documentation to collect them.

Comment: Yes, what you said is right, I saw the wrong host